# Store date from file in array

Tags: java

I am trying to to read in data file as an argument and store it into an array. I don't know how would I go about doing that.

In filename I have:

```
 Jane 24
 Cody 18
 Derek 25
```

What I have right now looks like this:

```
public void readAndPrint(String filename) {
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));

            while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String person = scan.next();
            int age = scan.nextInt();
            String[] personString = person.split(", ");

            System.out.println("Person: " + person + ", Age: " + age);
            for (int i = 0; i < personString.length; i++){
                personString[i] = person;
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(personString));
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now the result I have look like this:

```
[Jane]Person: Jane, Age: 24

[Cody]Person: Cody, Age: 18

[Derek]Person: Derek, Age: 25
```

The result I want:

```
Person: Jane, Age: 24

Person: Cody, Age: 18

Person: Derek, Age: 25

Jane, Cody, Derek,
```

Edited!

Comment: You need to know, in advance, the number of rows that are available

Comment: Have you asked your instructor about the nature of the problem and the material you are supposed to be learning?  (There are a number of ways which I could see doing this - creating a Person class, having a `Map<String, Integer>` to name two that come to mind right away) However, if you are supposed to be learning a specific technique, neither of those are appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelT - I want to store result from file in array and reuse array, but I don't know how to do that in array. Is that make sense?

Comment: Yes, though as I said, I would likely do it in ways that aren't appropriate for what is likely the homework assignment you are working on.  I would either be looking at `List<Person>` (ArrayList if you are doing lots of lookups, LinkedList if you are doing lots of inserts) or `Map<String,Integer>` (a TreeMap if sorted and LinkedHashMap if you are after insertion order, or HashMap if you don't care).  If those haven't been introduced to you yet and you are supposed to use some other approach, they are the very wrong answer for what is trying to be taught to you.

Comment: Is there a way to do this just only use simple array like the very basic one (without using ArrayList and Linklist)?

Comment: There are several ways to do it with simple arrays, depending on whether you want to set a limit on the maximum file size or not. If not, you need to be able to deal with enlarging the array when necessary.

Comment: One problem is that you have two different kinds of information here: a "name" String and an "age" int. However, arrays can store only a single type of information. One solution is to create two arrays, one for ages and one for names. Another solution is to create a `Person` class which holds the name and age for a person. Then you can create an array of `Person` objects. Most likely your instructor intends you use the second solution.

Comment: The result you say you want in your post looks like the result of just printing out the contents of the file. And it looks like your code does just that.

Comment: Nonetheless, I recommend storing the file contents as a String, splitting it on new lines ("\r?\n") (giving you an array), giving you the length of the array(s) you probably want to create in the end.

Comment: I recommend reading the array section of your textbook. It is much easier than you think, IF you try :).